# Simple animation using Css3

Tags: html, css

How can I make an HTML element like a circle act as if it was bouncing, like move it multiple times? is it possible with only CSS3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you'll need to use keyframe animations to do this. Here's a simple example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bounce"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@-webkit-keyframes hop {
       from{
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px);
        }


         to {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-30px);
        }  
      }

@-moz-keyframes hop {
       from{
        -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px);
        }


         to {
        -moz-transform: translate(0px,-30px);
        }  
      }

.bounce{
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:#ff6600;
    border-radius:300px;
    margin-top:100px;
-webkit-animation-name: hop;
    -webkit-animation-duration:.3s;
     -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-name: hop;
    -moz-animation-duration:.3s;
     -moz-animation-direction:alternate;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -moz-animation-delay:0s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

And a Fiddle for your viewing pleasure: http://jsfiddle.net/hpBhf/1/

Comment: Nice work! CSS3 rocks! (but jQuery animations are still more flexible and a LOT simpler) :D

Comment: You don't need all these properties. Use the animation shorthand instead and it would be reduced by 10 lines.

Comment: I know, but I figured that if someone didn't know all the properties for animations it'd be easier to understand what was happening if they were written out in full.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is using [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/), support a lot of different animation, if you want to quickly add animation, it is a very good choice, and here is simple game which developed by animate.css, http://www.gbin1.com/technology/democenter/20120812-animate-css/index.html